# 3d triangle in libgdx

Tags: java, 3d, libgdx

My problem is that in Libgdx, I created a triangle in 3D thanks to the Mesh class in this simple piece of code :

```
mesh = new Mesh(true, 3, 3, 
                new VertexAttribute(VertexAttributes.Usage.Position, 3, "vPosition"));

mesh.setVertices(new float[] { vert1.x, vert1.y, vert1.z, vert2.x, vert2.y, vert2.z, vert3.x, vert3.y, vert3.z });
mesh.setIndices(new short[] { 0, 1, 2 });
```

What is important for me is to be able to change the vert1, vert2, vert3, which store the triangle vertices coordinates, as I want to create the triangle during the game.

When the triangle is displayed, it seems to appear at the desired place, according to what I give him in the verts Vector3.

Now, here's the thing : I used to camera.rotateAround() to create a way to look around the scene and I also created a small box to see if my script with the camera is merely working. It is ! I can see my box rotating if I move the camera. But when I rotate around the scene, the triangle I created doesn't rotate and stays exactly motionless at the screen, just like it was a 2D mesh !

So here is my question : **How to make a 3D triangle in Libgdx and how to make a triangle render according to the camera movement ?**

Comment: API doc is not clear for me, but maybe the first parameter of the Mesh, a boolean isStatic variable, should be false.

Comment: Setting to false doesn't help, already tried. But thanks for trying, mate

Comment: The Mesh class is a pretty bare-bones wrapper around raw OpenGL, so there should be nothing especially "2d" about it.  Maybe show more code. How do you draw a working box?  Does your camera apply to the triangle render the same as the box render?  Are you recomputing the verts for the Mesh?

Comment: @P.T. Hm, maybe it comes from the way I render the triangle. In my render loop, I use this :

    this.shader.begin();
    mesh.render(this.shader, GL20.GL_TRIANGLES);
    this.shader.end();

and nothing else regarding the triangle. Maybe I have something to do, declare some projection matrix to use or something.

The way I rotate my camera is just simple : I use

    this.getCamera().rotateAround(Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Y, angle*this.mouseSensitivity*1000.0f);

So, I don't think it comes from this.

Comment: Please show more code ... OpenGL shaders need to have camera transformations applied explicitly.  Do you `update` your camera?  How are you rendering a 3D box?

Comment: @P.T. is correct we need to pass and multiply current camera projecton matrix in the shader with the current vertex position. Show the whole code of shader that you have used abd the code to render the triangle using shader prog.

Comment: Okay, thank you guys but I don't get why the shader is actually changing the geometry of my triangle. My shader is just a plain red texture. My problem is not that the paint I sprayed on the triangle is weird, my problem is that when I move my camera, the shape of my triangle is weird, as it is following the camera movement.

But I found a little clue here : http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/OpenGLMesh
This page says that "We define four vertices each composed of a position in window coordinates as well as a texture coordinate" WINDOWS coordinates. That would mean a Mesh is actually in 2D !

Comment: @turbodoom: that depends on you that you want to make the mesh 2d or 3d in your code you have made the mesh using all the vertices and you have created a triangle that means you have a 2d triangle in a 3d plane the various vertices defined generates a triangle in a particular 3d plane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution here : http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=10583&p=47800#p47800

That ImmediateModeRenderer20 gives a temporary way to create 3D meshes, including triangles.

It really seems that the libgdx Mesh class is only for 2D...

Comment: that's not correct you can create 3D elements as well.. it depends how you give the coordinates of vertices

Comment: ImmediateModeRender20 just makes the life easy by passing the cam.combined matrix to the code. internally it also sends the projection matrix to the shader to render the vertices